# How to click on "readonly" radio button using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

when I run the code the outer box gets selected but the radio button remains unselected.
PS: I'm doing a project To auto-buy product on an e-commerce website using chrome-driver.
Attached the image of a web element which I'm trying to access.
Code:

```
chrome_browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("PHONEPE").removeAttribute("readonly")')
cod = chrome_browser.find_element_by_id("PHONEPE")
chrome_browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cod)
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKCaW.jpg)
[image: UPDATE]

Comment: In your case the input is readonly so you cant click on it.

Comment: so there is no other way to click it through code?

Comment: You can try something like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` to perform js action on it.

Comment: @Dmitry I have tried what yu have suggested, The Code ran successfully but it selects the outer box of that radio button. The radio button still remains unselected.

Comment: I have updated the question and added a picture.

Comment: You can try to remove readonly attribute by executing this script driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("Element Id").removeAttribute("readonly")')

Comment: @Madkaikar I have tried it . but still the radio button isn't selected

Comment: code:
chrome_browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("PHONEPE").removeAttribute("readonly")')
cod = chrome_browser.find_element_by_id("PHONEPE")
chrome_browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cod)